# Have put me out of admin

Tags: filesystem, permissions, root

Installed a new user and then tried to create one with the name root, because sudo
nerves. Didnot work and i have learnt in the meantime, this is not possible.

I am now unable to login into user "admin". It complains that /home/marek/.ICEauthority could not be updated.

I have another user which can login. sudo under the new user does not work and it complains a unsuccessful attempt has been reported.

How can I fix the .ICEAuthority permissions to use this login?                                                                                     > SOLUTION: First log in on terminal with ctrl+alt+F1 as admin, so this was possible, only on destop not.  Second gave me all rights in /home/marek back with **bold***sudo chmod -R u+rw /home/marek*.    For me it seems, that the error message shows .ICEauthority file and there no rw-rights for admin, but really during my triing to create a root-account ubuntu has deleted my admin-rights somewhere else, because i was still admin and could change user-accounts and have given back only me all rw-rights. Sounds a little bit strange.

Comment: forgot:ubuntu 11.10 64bit.  As installer i am admin, but on the terminal i am not root, instead marek, and this seemed not to work as root, so i used sudo: but this is debian style only, so confusion.

Comment: what was the first user you created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root is the first user created in almost every distribution. So please do not try to create a root user.

To run applications as root including shell(which means basically means becoming root) in Ubuntu all one needs is to run sudo. Sudo is very useful.

```
sudo application_name options
```

This is the way to use sudo. to solve the ICE issue. You need to change the ownership of the file to the user running the shell.
Type this command.

```
 sudo chown marek:marek /home/marek/.ICEauthority
```

I assume marek is the username as it is in the directory /home/marek. Login as the first user created while setting up Ubuntu and then run the sudo chown command as above.

Corrections: the marek does not need to be the first user. Though the password would be the password of the one is in. 
Corrections: Added changes for users who are not in sudoers list.

Comment: please check the edits above

Comment: no go new user doesn´t allow sudo

Comment: well. login as admin user and run the command as given above.

Comment: marek, new one is standard martin

Comment: that is the problem, how?

Comment: so admin user does not exist ?

Comment: still there, but as written above, i cannot log in.

Comment: you mean you forgot your admin password?

Comment: no, the .ICE file cannot be updated

Comment: press ctrl+alt+F1 and login there. LightDM would not complain about ICE file.

Comment: that works, sudo chown without error, but still same error! How to go from terminal to normal destop?

Comment: good to know that you have not forgotten your password. now run
`sudo chown admin:admin /home/admin/.ICEauthority`

Comment: no same; admin:admin doesn´t work, but marek:admin. I am still admin, but the error resists to go. I must breakdown the system to go from terminal back, what is the right one like start destop?

Comment: Ihave looked, it is as i thought, in .ICE the admin group has no rights

Comment: @Marek Can you update your question with what you are trying instead of burying it in comments? Your question is very hard to read, we need you to summarize your problem better up front so we can help!

Comment: yes, Ubuntu 11.10 64bit. Error while logging in: Cannot update /home/marek/.ICEauthority  .In the meantime i can work in terminal as sudo with ctrl+alt+F1 and know, that the file has no rights for the admin-group, only for me as admin marek. So this right has to be set. Also i don´t know the command to start from terminal the graphic-destop and must break down the system to go back.

Comment: @Marek why not rename the .ICEauthority file temporarily. `mv /home/marek/.ICEauthority /home/marek/.OldICEauthority` and this would let you log in to that login

Comment: no doesn´t work, same error

Comment: It is done, please look update above. Gave me as admin all rights in /home/me/ again. So stop here, but i want to learn, why this worked, above please. Thanks to viyyer.

Comment: Please documents the steps you have done as an update to the question and possibly close the question by marking the answer with a tick mark.